# Why does Chartjs line chart does not animate to new values?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I am using a [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) line chart showing time data where I want to update with new values from an ajax call.

I have time on the X axis (1 days on 15 minutes intervals) , and just numbers for the Y axis.

So it looks like the following..

[image: Graph]

My setup is as follows.

```
        this.chartSetup = {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: this.times,
            datasets: [{
              fill: true,
              lineTension: 0.1,
              backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
              borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
              label: title,
              data: this.vals,
              pointRadius: 0,
            }]
          },
          options: {
            spanGaps: true,
            legend: {
              position: 'bottom',
              labels: {
                boxWidth: 10
              }
            },
            tooltips: {
              enabled: false
            },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  stepSize: 6,
                  unitStepSize: 5
                },
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                  displayFormats: {
                    hour: 'h:mm a',
                    minute: 'h:mm a',
                  }
                }
              }],
            },
          }
        };

   Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = "easeOutBounce";
   this.chart = new Chart(this.canvas.nativeElement, this.chartSetup);
```

When the chart first draws it **animates** the new values. However, if I then remove the data, and add a new set, it **does not animate** to the new values.

For example, to mimic new server data, using a timer, if I do the following,
where `this.times` holds the X data, `this.vals` holds the Y..

```
setTimeout(() => {
  let temp = this.makeDummyData(20);
  //let dataToUpdate = (<any>(this.chart.data)).datasets[0].data;
  //let labels = (<any>(this.chart.data)).labels;     
  this.times.splice(0, this.times.length);      
  this.vals.splice(0, this.vals.length);
  for (let item of temp) {
    this.times.push(item.time);
    this.vals.push(item.val);

  }

  this.chart.update();
}, 8000)
```

The chart does update, but it does not have any **animation**, it just jumps straight to the new display. If I just date the exiting data without removing it first, does **does animate** to the new display.

Is there any reason the **animation** does not work when I replace the data as in the above example?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue but in my case, I was seeing the same animation on update as on first time plotting the chart. https://jsfiddle.net/uLf6hgnx/3/